# gradle properties information

Tags: properties, gradle

I have following properties in gradle.properties file:

```
prop1=/a/b/c
prop2=abc.txt
```

How I can set 
     prop3=prop1/prop2 in gradle.properties?

enter code hereAny kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set a third property with the _values_ of prop1 and prop2? Something like "prop3=${prop1}/${prop2}?

Comment: Yes exactly the same

Comment: I tried prop3=prop1/prop2 and prop3=${prop1}/${prop2} but both are not working

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic property evaluation is not possible within the `gradle.properties` file. However, you can do the evaluation of `prop3` within your `build.gradle` file.

```
ext.prop3 = "${prop1}/${prop2}"
```

`prop3` can then be used within your build script as a project property (like `prop1` and `prop2`)